# Samsung Note 4 was stolen. Can I get my contacts, pictures, and SMS back?

Tags: samsung

My Samsung Note 4 was stolen today at the movies. Is there any way I can get all my pictures, contacts and SMS back? It's synched to my Gmail account almost daily when connected to wifi.

Honestly, ordering a new phone isn't a big deal, but I had priceless information and pictures on the phone.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

**What you can restore from Google is limited to what you backed up to it.**

Make sure to go [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) and remove your device so that the person who has your phone right now can not mess up with your Google account as well.